# SharePoint VS ASP.NET Development

Tags: sharepoint

I have a situation where I need to develop an application which has 20% features like document management, document search, wikis and blogs which can be implemented in SharePoint. Rest 80% are custom features. Moreover only the 20% features related data (like documents, wiki & blogs) should be in SharePoint database. Rest 80% features data should be managed in seperate SQL Server Database.

Given this situtaion,

I have two approaches to proceed.

Approach 1: Implement all the features (including custom) in SharePoint

Approach 2: Implement SharePoint Features in SharePoint, and have another ASP.NET application to implement the 80% custom features. For retrieving blog info or wiki in ASP.NET application use SharePoint Web Services.

Please let me know which approach is better one?

Comment: if in both case you would use sharepoint.Then why you not use only sharepoint for whole scenerio.only drawback is sharepoint is very costly in terms of money and resources.

Comment: The 80% custom features is not available in SharePoint OOB, it has to be developed in ASP.NET, if this is the case what is the point of developing it in ASP.NET and just hosting it in SharePoint?